# sql insert into with sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, subquery

I want to run this query

```
INSERT INTO [tblPollLogs]
           ([lastModified]
           ,[ip]
           ,[a1]
           ,[a2]
         )
     VALUES
           (getdate()
           ,'aaa'
           ,(select top 1 header from [tblPollAnswer] where [pollAnswerId] = @param1)
           ,(select top  1 header from [tblPollAnswer] where [pollAnswerId] = @param2)         
         )
```

But I get the error

Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

can i run this query in one query or i need get the values before running this query

thanks

Comment: In SQL Server 2008+ subqueries are fine there. BTW: Why are you using `top 1` with no `order by`? If there is more than one matching row it is undeterministic what will be inserted and if there isn't more than one matching row you don't need the `top 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change it to `insert...select`  as below

```
INSERT INTO [tblPollLogs]
           ([lastModified]
           ,[ip]
           ,[a1]
           ,[a2]
         )
select getdate(),
       'aaa',
      (select top 1 header from [tblPollAnswer] where [pollAnswerId] = @param1),
      (select top  1 header from [tblPollAnswer] where [pollAnswerId] = @param2)
```